# RecyclerView.ItemDecorator left padding

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am using the https://gist.github.com/polbins/e37206fbc444207c0e92 ItemDecorator to draw a separator line under each item in a recycler view. However it draws a straight line from left to right.

```
@Override
public void onDrawOver(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
    int left = parent.getPaddingLeft();
    int right = parent.getWidth() - parent.getPaddingRight();

    int childCount = parent.getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
        View child = parent.getChildAt(i);

        RecyclerView.LayoutParams params = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();

        int top = child.getBottom() + params.bottomMargin;
        int bottom = top + mDivider.getIntrinsicHeight();

        mDivider.setBounds(left, top, right, bottom);
        mDivider.draw(c);
    }
}
```

How can I set a left non absolute padding to the separator like in the picture below? Is this even possible using ItemDecorator?

[image]

I could modify this

```
int left = parent.getPaddingLeft();
```

but it would be absolute. Any ideas?

How it looks like right now:

[image]

Item layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="@drawable/recycler_item_background">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mTextViewIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="@string/fa_search"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/wrapper"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/mTextViewIcon"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/mTextViewIcon"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="25dp"
        android:paddingStart="25dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mTextViewTitle"
            style="@style/Subhead"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mTextViewSubtitle"
            style="@style/SmallGray"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

View holder:

```
public static class ItemViewHolder extends BaseViewHolder {

    @Bind(R.id.mTextViewIcon)
    TextView mTextViewIcon;

    @Bind(R.id.mTextViewTitle)
    TextView mTextViewTitle;

    @Bind(R.id.mTextViewSubtitle)
    TextView mTextViewSubtitle;

    public ParkzoneViewHolder(View mView) {
        super(mView);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, mView);
    }
}
```

I am using TextView for the icon with a custom typeface, just for you're information.

Comment: what do you mean by non absolute padding?

Comment: @Bhargav I mean it is a bad idea to give it a padding of say 100px.

Comment: but its not absolute, left is calculated from the padding you have given to its parent, it would've been absolute if you had done `int left = 100`

Comment: @Bhargav you're right. But how would a layout, that contains an icon and a title, look like when you give the parent a padding? Say you give it a left padding of 100. The icon would be padded aswell.

Comment: So the image you posted is how you want it to look, can you post an image of how it looks right now?

Comment: btw since you have the `recyclerview parent` you can just get the viewholder for for `i` , then get the width of the imageview's layout and set that as the left bound of your drawable

Comment: @Bhargav just tried, if(child.getId() == R.id.iconview) but it is never entered

Comment: no no, the child's ID wont be equal to the id of your imageview layout, if possible could you post your viewholder and also the recyclerview item's layout, ill compile a solution for you from it

Comment: @Bhargav ok, see my edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try

```
public static class ItemViewHolder extends BaseViewHolder {

    @Bind(R.id.mTextViewIcon)
    TextView mTextViewIcon;

    @Bind(R.id.mTextViewTitle)
    TextView mTextViewTitle;

    @Bind(R.id.mTextViewSubtitle)
    TextView mTextViewSubtitle;

    @Bind(R.id.wrapper)
    LinearLayout mWrapperLayout;

    public ParkzoneViewHolder(View mView) {
        super(mView);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, mView);
    }
}

@Override
public void onDrawOver(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
    int right = parent.getWidth() - parent.getPaddingRight();

    int childCount = parent.getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
        // You can get view holders from recyclerview in different ways,
        // parent.getChildViewHolder(child)
        // im thinking parent.getChildViewHolder(child) 
        // is reliable and so ill use that here.
        // but you be sure to test it with the other methods too
        // if the getChildViewHolder doesnt work
        View child = parent.getChildAt(i);
        ItemViewHolder holder = (ItemViewHolder) parent.getChildViewHolder(child);
        int left = parent.getPaddingLeft() + child.getPaddingLeft() 
                        + holder.mTextViewIcon.getPaddingLeft() + holder.mTextViewIcon.getWidth() 
                            + holder.mWrapperLayout.getPaddingLeft();
        RecyclerView.LayoutParams params = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();

        int top = child.getBottom() + params.bottomMargin;
        int bottom = top + mDivider.getIntrinsicHeight();

        mDivider.setBounds(left, top, right, bottom);
        mDivider.draw(c);
    }
}
```

Comment: But I think `parent.getChildViewHolder(child)` is not very memory effecient compared to `parent.findViewHolderForLayoutPosition(i)` , and also add null checks to make sure you get around null pointer exceptions

Comment: @artworkadシ your welcome :) , the code could be improved upon for efficiency, like hold a local reference for `holder.mTextViewIcon`, since its used twice and in a for loop

Comment: Okay, I am going to have a look at that. I have another problem with the recycler view, maybe you can help me out on that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35805723/recyclerview-does-not-recycle-custom-text-view-properly